# Error when requesting a list of Bookable Rooms through Social Tables API

Tags: social-tables

When I execute a GET request to the following URL to query a list of Bookable Rooms, I receive the below 405 error response. Can do I resolve this error?

Request URL (GET):

```
https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/bookable-rooms?page_size=50
```

Response JSON (405)

```
{
  "code": "MethodNotAllowedError",
  "message": "GET is not allowed"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The api actually has changed to https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/rooms but our docs do not reflect this recent change yet.

Also be aware that you will only be able to see rooms that are tied to your account so if your account hasn't gone through an onboarding process to get CAD files for your properties it won't return anything.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I gave this a try, but it returned "{"code":404,"message":"Not Found"}"

Here's how I executed the request. Any thoughts on what might be going wrong?

curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer MY_BEARER_TOKEN' 'https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/rooms'

Comment: FYI: StackOverflow takes out the "https' prefix in the URL when posting a comment. When testing my cUrl request, you will need to add it back in.

Comment: Hey Dan, Looks like your account doesn't have any floor plans attached so the 404 is the correct message.

Comment: I can confirm that Cooper Triggs has added several floor plans to our account. I can see them in the Venues area when logged into the app. I can even choose them successfully for a new event. I would like to confirm: Are you looking at the correct account? Our account email address starts with 'unleashedadmin'.

Comment: Okay cool I was looking at the wrong account.  Yeah you now have access to three properties.  So you want to get their ids by hitting https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/properties with your token and then you can individually hit https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/properties/:property_id/rooms endpoints to get the rest of the data.  Thanks for your patience we'll be trying to get the docs up to date soon.

Comment: Thanks! I will do this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to view rooms for 2 our of 3 properties successfully. However, for property with id 'cj1i1vbwk01hv0f4jukjbd7su' no rooms are returned. When I view this property in Social Tables, I see many rooms (eg. Concourse, 2nd Floor). Why can't I view them through the API?

curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN' 'https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/properties/cj1i1vbwk01hv0f4jukjbd7su/rooms'